# Connect 4 with 2 slots name?

Tags: connect-four

Alright, so I had this game for a while, it's a connect 4 , but each column has 2 slots. Some pieces, (called "blockers" take up both slots in the column) I'm not sure if I have enough pieces and blockers, to look it up I need the name. But I no longer have the box and cannot remember it.

Do anybody know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like "Connect 4x4". 
Is this it:
http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/42685/connect-4x4